# How to open an application on active display while using Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I am using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
```

to open a TEXT file in notepad from within my windows form application.

Detailed code snippet is

```
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", LogFile);
PSI.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PSI);
```

However, it opens notepad on the default desktop but not on the extended desktop on which the main application is running.

Now, the question is, how to open notepad on the active desktop i.e. Window on which the current application is running?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be change your primary monitor in windows. Otherwise your going to have to invoke some pretty heavy libraries.   You will have to use FindWindow, SetWindowPos, EnumWIndows.

Comment: I think this question is made confusing using the term "Window", perhaps "Display" or "Monitor" would be a better choice?

Comment: You don't need `FindWindow`. If you create the process the returned `Process` class has a `MainWindowHandle` property.

Comment: @Anon That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Other that specifying the initial window state (normal, hidden, etc), you have basically no control over how the newly launched application starts up and where it shows itself.

The best bet here is to launch the application, then use its window handle to tell it to move. This all requires using P/Invoke,  to call [`MoveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The C# signatures for all of those functions are on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).

Here's a very [simple (VB.NET) example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/b22ad05b-c8d1-4bc1-bcc3-0cfe714649b6/) that shows the basic idea. In this case, as @Lloyd points out, the window handle you need is the `Process.MainWindowHandle` you get back from `Process.Start`. Note that `Process.MainWindowHandle` isn't filled in immediately; you typically need to call `WaitForInputIdle` to make sure the window actually gets created. If `MainWindowHandle` is 0 then you'll know it's too soon.

Comment: You might also need to call `Process.Refresh()`.